# Setting up default compiler in Mac os X 10.6 for eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, macos, fortran

This is my first question here.

I am having trouble setting up Eclipse in Mac Os X 10.6 for compiling Fortran codes. I need to use Eclipse to write a mixed code using both C++ and Fortran. I am using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2. The problem starts with Apple's default compiler GCC 4.2 which doesn't have Fortran enabled. I installed GCC 4.6 given [here](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) and have managed to get it working in Terminal. But still Eclipse and Xcode both use the 4.2 and I can't find a way to change the settings. Can you help me with this problem? I prefer not to the delete the default GCC 4.2. I just want to get eclipse to use 4.6.

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem by using NetBeans instead of Eclipse. I simply set up a second compiler profile directed to /usr/local/bin where GCC 4.6 is installed if you use the package provided by [HPC](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/). It automatically detected everything it needs and everything is looking good.